# Sort the repositories by quantity of stars using github.api and angular

Tags: javascript, angular, sorting, github-api

Im looking for a way to order the repositories shown by stars desc using angular

i've tried to add let repo of repos | orderBy

but isn't working

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Repos</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" *ngFor="let repo of repos">
        <p class="clearfix">
            <span class="repo-title">{{repo.name}}</span>
            <a href="{{repo.html_url}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning pull-right" 
               target="_blank">Veja este projeto no Github</a>
        </p>
       <p>{{repo.description}}</p>
       <p><img class="star" src="../../../assets/img/star.png" alt="">{{repo.stargazers_count}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike AngularJS, Angular 2+ does not provide `orderBy` pipes for filtering and sorting lists as they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification (reference: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Instead, you can sort the data in your component using the Array `sort()` method.

To sort repositories by stars in ascending order:

```
this.repos.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.stargazers_count - b.stargazers_count;
});
```

Similarly, to sort repositories by stars in descending order:

```
this.repos.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.stargazers_count - a.stargazers_count;
});
```